# Frontmatter and hyperref won't work together!

Tags: hyperref

I have a document in which there is an 'Abstract' section before my ToC. The Abstract part is added to test if it would work, but when I click on it on my ToC, it goes to the front page, my title page, and not the Abstract page. Please help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.8in, bottom=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breaklinks, colorlinks,linkcolor=NavyBlue, citecolor=Blue, urlcolor=Blue, linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{Blue}\leaders\hrule height \footrulewidth\hfill}}

\newcommand{\dl}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip15pt}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\textbf{.}}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries \fontsize{30}{0}\selectfont \fontfamily{put}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries \fontsize{14}{0}\selectfont \fontfamily{put}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{ \fontsize{11}{0}\selectfont \fontfamily{put}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\vskip1ex}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{ \fontsize{11}{0}\selectfont \fontfamily{put}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecafterpnum}{\vskip1ex}




\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{25ex}
\rule{6.5in}{2pt}\\
[-2ex]
\rule{6.5in}{1pt}\\
[4.5mm]
{\fontsize{38}{0}\selectfont \bfseries \scshape  \color{Blue}Git\color{blue}ter\color{Blue}lig\color{blue}ning} \\
\rule{6.5in}{1pt}\\
[-1.8ex]
\rule{6.5in}{2pt}\\
[14ex]
{ \fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont Ali, Casper, Jannick \& San}\\
[3ex]
{\large \scshape 1.z} \\
\vspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{C:/LaTeX/Next.png} \\
[4mm]
\small{\bfseries Albertslund Gymnasium \& HF} \\
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage

\renewcommand\contentsname{Indhold \vspace{3ex}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\section*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
Bla. bla. bla.
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\fontsize{50}{0}\selectfont \color{Blue} \thesection}
{1ex}
{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\section}{10pt}{6ex}{4ex}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Regneopgaver}
\subsection{Opg. 1}
```

Comment: you specify `inputenc` twice, both times with the non standard utf8x option, it's probaly better to use the standard utf8 (or with recent latex  releases, you do not need inputenc at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an anchor (`\phantomsection`) before the abstract:

```
\phantomsection
\section*{Abstract}
```